# Hypothesis Testing: Uniform Distribution

Tags: statistics

Given there is a number generator which generates random numbers 0 to 9. Given after 50 number generations only 5 of the generated numbers are below 3 (i.e. 0,1 or 2) and the significance level is $\alpha$ = 1%. How can I test if for this significance level the number generator is generating all numbers with equal probability?

It is clear to me that if the number generator would be indeed generating the numbers with uniform probability, one would expect 15 generated numbers between 0 and 2 - but how do I test the nullhypothesis in this case precisely?

Answer (score 2):

The distribution of the number of results 0, 1 or 2 is binomial $(n,p)$ with $n=50$ and $p=3/10$ hence the p-value is $p=\mathbb P[X\leqslant5]$ where $X$ is binomial $(50,3/10)$, that is,
$$
p=\sum_{k=0}^5{50\choose k}\cdot\left(\frac7{10}\right)^{50-k}\cdot\left(\frac3{10}\right)^k.
$$

Comment: why is p 1/3 and not 3/10?

Comment: and I don't really understand the calculation of the p-value...

Comment: Sorry for the confusion about 1/3 vs 3/10, see edited answer. "I don't really understand the calculation of the p-value..." OK, but if you do not describe more precisely what you do not understand, I am afraid I cannot explain more.

Comment: So, as I understand the p-value, calculating the p-value here means to calculate the probability that out of 50 generated numbers we indeed observe 5 numbers under 3. The probability of a generated number under 3 is - given the generator generateds uniformly - 3/10 and hence the counter probability 7/10. Understood. But why is it then (7/10) to the power of 50? Where does the 50 come from? Why do we have three summands...? I just dont see how you came up with the formula above..thanks!

Comment: Pffew... I seem to have some trouble simply **reading** the question... :-) Sorry (bis) about that. See re-revised version.

Comment: Oh..now it looks understandable :D thanks! I guess the test is onsided and hence we have to reject the nullhypothesis. Is this correct?

Comment: If p<1%, yes. $ $